# How to add a field/column of a document set to the "Document Set Properties" WebPart

Tags: document-set, welcome-page

I created a new column to a document set. Afterwards I looked at the welcome page with a "document set properites"-Webpart, how ever the new column was not present. So how do I add this new column to this webpart on the welcome page

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "Library Setting" of the document set
2. Select the content type of interest
3. Go to "document set settings"
4. Under the section "Welcome Page Columns", select fields (columns) needed for the Document Set Properties Webpart

After this steps the values of the column are available on the welcome page